# All categories except some categoryID

Tags: php, categories

This `if ($Category->CategoryID > 0)` is for all categories. How to eliminate some categoryID like 1, 2 and 3.

```
      if ($Category->CategoryID > 0) {
     // If we are below the max depth, and there are some child categories
     // in the $ChildCategories variable, do the replacement.
     if ($Category->Depth < $MaxDisplayDepth && $ChildCategories != '') {
        $CatList = str_replace('{ChildCategories}', '<span class="ChildCategories">'.Wrap(T('Child Categories:'), 'b').' '.$ChildCategories.'</span>', $CatList);
        $ChildCategories = '';
     }

     if ($Category->Depth >= $MaxDisplayDepth && $MaxDisplayDepth > 0) {
        if ($ChildCategories != '')
           $ChildCategories .= ', ';
        $ChildCategories .= Anchor(Gdn_Format::Text($Category->Name), '/categories/'.$Category->UrlCode);
     } else if (($DoHeading || $DoHeadings) && $Category->Depth == 1) {
        $CatList .= '<li class="Item CategoryHeading Title Info Depth1 Category-'.$Category->UrlCode.' '.$CssClasses.'">
           <div class="ItemContent Category">'.Anchor(Gdn_Format::Text($Category->Name), '/categories/'.$Category->UrlCode).'</div>'
           .GetOptions($Category, $this).'
        </li>';
        $Alt = FALSE;
     } else {
        $LastComment = UserBuilder($Category, 'LastComment');
        $AltCss = $Alt ? ' Alt' : '';
        $Alt = !$Alt;
        $CatList .= '<li class="'.$Category->Depth.$AltCss.' Category-'.$Category->UrlCode.' '.$CssClasses.'">
           <div class="SubMenu1 Category '.$CssClasses.'">'
              .Anchor(Gdn_Format::Text($Category->Name), '/categories/'.$Category->UrlCode, 'Title')
              .GetOptions($Category, $this)
              .Wrap($Category->Description, 'div', array('class' => 'CategoryDescription'))
              .'<div class="Meta2">
                 ';
                 if ($Category->LastCommentID != '' && $Category->LastDiscussionTitle != '') {
                    $CatList .= '<span class="LastDiscussionTitle">'.sprintf(
                          T('Most recent: %1$s by %2$s'),
                          Anchor(SliceString($Category->LastDiscussionTitle, 40), '/discussion/'.$Category->LastDiscussionID.'/'.Gdn_Format::Url($Category->LastDiscussionTitle)),
                          UserAnchor($LastComment)
                       ).'</span>'
                       .'<span class="LastCommentDate">'.Gdn_Format::Date($Category->DateLastComment).'</span>';
                 }

              $CatList .= '</div>
           </div>
        </li>';
     }
  }
```

Comment: Instead if you know which categories you want you can use MySQL IN() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specifically don't want categories 1, 2, and 3 (very limited solution):

```
if ($Category->CategoryID > 3)
```

Or if you know which categories you don't want:

```
if (!in_array($Category->CategoryID, array(1, 2, 3)))
```

Or if you are figuring out which categories you don't want earlier in the code:

```
$bad_categories = array();

//populate $bad_categories to fit your needs...

if (!in_array($Category->CategoryID, $bad_categories))
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to check the numbers you do not want for example.

Changing this line

```
if ($Category->CategoryID > 0) {
```

To this

```
if ($Category->CategoryID != 1) {
```

Will mean you do not get category 1.

To remove a couple of categories use this.

```
if ($Category->CategoryID != 1 && $Category->CategoryID != 2) {
```

You can continue this indefinitely. But as Abhishek kadadi suggest in the comments using MySQL may also be a solution.

However obviously if you add any other categories, you would need to hardcode it if it were not to be seen.

Potentially you could add another field in the db, ie. visible, those visible will be shown etc. Then you could do a MySQL query for only visible ones and simply adding a new category and visibility would be all that was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Consider filter categories in the SQL statement, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field_name NOT IN (1,2,3)
```